# Set Repeating Alarm Every Day at Specific time In Android

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager

I am using Alarm manager to run alarm at specific time every day. Below is the code

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OnAlarmReceive.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

I am Setting alarm at 12AM every day. And Below is the code for BroadCastReciever

```
@Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
           System.out.println("Time is 12 Am");
           Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
    }
```

Problem in this code is Alarm is Triggered As soon as i Run the Application Irrespective of time. Any help will be Appreciated. Thank You

Comment: you can go through the link.It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885198/repeat-alarm-everyday-at-specific-time-alarm-manager

Answer (score 9):

The alarm will only fire immediately if you set the alarm in the past.
E.g. it is now 10:00h and you want to set an alarm every day at 09:00. To avoid this, you have to look what time it is now, and shift the alarm 1 day if that is the case... This allows you to use the `setRepeating` method (which is more precise than `setInexactRepeating`)

This fixes the issue:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

if(Calendar.getInstance().after(calendar)){
    // Move to tomorrow
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

//... continue like before by setting the alarm
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue as you and I couldn't get it to work. Plus all the examples I could find were also setting a specific date, not only just a time. This should work for you:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this , NotifyService.class);     
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ThisActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent); //Repeat every 24 hours
```

Hope this helps you fix your problem!

Comment: Same shit man. I want the alarm to be at either AM or PM. If I set the alarm to the next minute of the current hour it still goes off regardless of the time of the day (AM or PM).

Answer (score 2):

try to use this:

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(cal.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
    }
```