# Android automatically delete records after specific time

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am creating an Android app in which i will receive SMS and store it in SQlite database. i have achieved database functionalities i.e insert, update, delete and show etc. Here is my code:

```
public void addRecord(String number){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_BLOCKEDLIST, number);
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_BLOCKEDLIST, null,values);
    db.close();
}

//delete record from database
public void deletRecord(String nummber){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_BLOCKEDLIST + " WHERE " + COLUMN_BLOCKEDLIST + "=\"" + nummber + "\";");
    db.close();
}

//show all records from database

public String showAllRecords(){
String allRecords = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_BLOCKEDLIST + " WHERE 1";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        allRecords += cursor.getString(0) + "\n";
    }
    db.close();
return allRecords;
}
```

now i need the functionally to delete every SMS after 24 hour of its insertion time. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to delete specifically in 24 hours after inserted? or just delete data older than 24h when the app is opened?

Answer (score 1):

when you received sms get the current time then minus the 24 hours from current time(get the time value).Then perform delete operation when time is before on that value.(write code SMS onreceive method).

Thats its. when you received sms its automatically delete the old message that before 24 hours.if some case you not receive any sms for few days its not deleted so call the same method code in application activity oncreate also..

Comment: i don't want to do it from insert or show function call. As you know receiving time is not fix and i want to delete it on exact time as well as automatically, not by user. I want it to be like alarm such that whenever the fix time come the alarm starts and the user don't need to open alarm app or do anything.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751294/set-repeating-alarm-every-day-at-specific-time-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could insert a column INSERTION_TIME in the TABLE_BLOCKEDLIST database when you will create a Date instance of insertion, and compare it with the current date. If it's longer than 24 hours, delete it.
If you receive twice or more in 24 hours, you can do this check when calling methods addRecord, deleteRecord or showAllRecords.
If you want your app to check the database for such records in, let's say, 5 minutes, you can create a long running service that will implement this functionality (BroadcastReceiver).

Comment: Adding insertion time isn't an issue. The issue is how to compare it with current time because the time is changing every second. I m newbie to Android, will you please elaborate how to receive broadcast from system clock or just provide the code. what will happen if i want it after 48 hours. i mean how can i handle date because AM and PM with time is not enough in that case.

Comment: Date now = new Date(); //creates a Date instance with the current time