# How to download images from the Internet and set them as background in runtime multiple times?

Tags: java, android, performance

I have such task: need to download images from the internet and set them as view's background every 15 minutes (user sets the period).
I have done something like that:

I have `JobService`, it downloads images and saves them as files to created directory. After it send broadcast, receiver takes it and sets file names to it's listener. Listener - my class `LauncherApplication` extends Application, it is created before all activities, I save it's instance and thus I can load images from files in every part of program.I do it with such `AsyncTask`, execute it if necessary in `OnResume()` :

```
public class BackgroundImageAsyncChanger extends AsyncTask<String, Void ,Drawable> {

    private int pictureNumber;
    private View backgroundView;
    private Context context;

    public BackgroundImageAsyncChanger(View backgroundView, Context context, int pictureNumber) {
        this.backgroundView = backgroundView;
        this.context = context;
        this.pictureNumber = pictureNumber;
    }

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String ... imageFilesNames) {
        final int index = pictureNumber;
        final Bitmap bitmap = ImageFileOperator.getInstance().loadImage(context, imageFilesNames[index]);
        final Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
        return drawable;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable backgroundImage) {
        backgroundView.setBackground(backgroundImage);
    }
}
```

**And so there is the problem. It's takes time to download images from the Internet, and when they are downloaded after the Activity/Fragment OnResume() , it doesn't change background.**
How I can implement it better?

Thanks every one for answers!

Comment: Try change background during onClick. Perhaps problem in `backgroundView.setBackground(backgroundImage)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better from downloading the image. Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

**picasso** is simple to use

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView);
```

**Glide**

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(imgUrl)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView);
```

in both the case you not need to worry about downloading the image.As soon as it get load it automatically project on image view. And automatically cache management.

/*********************************************************/

since every 15 min your job scheduler take url from server or whatever so suppose you have a function call

```
    private void jobScheduler(){
    new url generates here
    call the function to load image and send the url as paramater
         loadImages(url);
      }
```

here you load the url in same pitcure again and again after every **15 min**

```
 private void loadImages(String url){
    Picasso.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
        .into(imageView);
    }
```

Comment: But how can I upgrade images every 15 min?

Comment: is the link of the image is changing in every 15 min?

Comment: I have JobService and it works every 15 min and takes new urls

Comment: use a background thread so that it in every 15 min it is going to call the function which is responsible for loading of image or as soon as our job service take new url then call that loading image function

Comment: Can you explain please? Also, can I use Glide to set image to View?

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm gonna try it!

Comment: Actually there is a problem... I need to load image into View, not ImageView. And I can't do it with Picasso/Glide.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading every image can lead to memory leak and its not a good idea.

You can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Here is the working example:

```
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageUrl) // or URI/path
                .placeholder(placeholder)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
                .error(placeholder)
                .skipMemoryCache(false)
                .dontAnimate()
                .listener(listener) // you can skip this if do not want to handle callback
                .into(imageView); //imageview to set thumbnail to.
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: But how can I upgrade images every 15 min?

Comment: upgrade...? do you want upload images to server...?

Comment: I need to load image into View, not ImageView. And I can't do it with Picasso/Glide...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading image,
you can directly load image using third party like picasso/glide.

**Picasso**

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.img_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.img_error)
    .into(mImageView);
```

**Glide**

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .thumbnail(0.5f)
    .crossFade()
    .skipMemoryCache(false)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .listener(mImagelistener)//optional
    into(mImageView);
```

To upgrade images every specific interval,
You can set repeating alarm to send specific broadcast at some interval.
refer: [Set Repeating Alarm Every Day at Specific time In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751294/set-repeating-alarm-every-day-at-specific-time-in-android)
or
you can timer/handler class to get event on specific interval.
(Use based on your app structure)

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a similar service to configure wallpapers, the schedule task is managing by a "job service"

```
        MyService myService;
Handler myHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        myService = (MyService) msg.obj;
        myService.setUICallback(YourActivity.this);
    }
};

myServiceComponent = new ComponentName(this, MyService.class);
```

settings:

```
                JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, myServiceComponent);
            //builder.setRequiresCharging(true);
            //builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true);
            builder.setExtras(bundle);//if you need
            builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED);//only wifi
            builder.setPeriodic(900000);//15 min, dont try set less
            builder.setPersisted(true);

            myService.scheduleJob(builder.build());
```

and tasks in a jobservice class

```
public class MyService extends JobService{}
```

check this [tutorial for jobservice](https://www.developer.com/ws/android/how-to-schedule-background-tasks-in-android-apps-using-the-jobscheduler-api.html)

spam:you can see de live project [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=test.darioreal.com.meteo01)