# I wanna make smth like this :( if time " now " = 5:50 pm) do // Somthing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanna do just like Alarm in time , but as I said in the question 
I wanna make smth like this :( if time " now " = 5:50 pm) do // Something 
i tried this but it's take all my battery life time : 
what I've Done is Set int Hours and int minutes  and then

```
enter code here
while (true){
if (Hours==x &minutes==y )
//do somethin

}
so any better way ?
```

Comment: Try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885198/repeat-alarm-everyday-at-specific-time-alarm-manager

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Never do a `while(true){}` loop, is takes to much memory.

A thing you could do is use a `Handler`. It will call `Runnable` you gave him after the delay you want :

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //do your stuff here, even start a new handler
  }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

You can launch him every minut for exemple and check if it is the good time or not, or every hour, just calcul when you want him to wake up.

Comment: U mean handler Will launch the Activity In specific time ! ?
Need it in background I use service to work in background .. my Activity work find but as u said it take memory and Battery sooo much  so looking for better way Can u help ?\

Comment: It will depend what you tell the handler to do and if you app is on bg or not..

Comment: ok can u give me an example how to make the handler give toast in specific time ?

Comment: Just make your runnable show a toast,  something like `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), yourString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: The Problem is ..that If i use if () in run() it will give the Toast when i run the App in that time I specified but if not .. will do nth ... that y I use wihle(true )....

Comment: Did you check the alarm manager?

Comment: As chol said, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885198/repeat-alarm-everyday-at-specific-time-alarm-manager

Comment: So I should use : 
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int h = c.set(Hours,18);
int m = c.set(Minute,30)
in Hours = 18;
int Minuts=30;
now how should make  the Toast appear in that time (Hours,Minuts)?